# Install Ubuntu on clean disk - on 100GB only

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I don't know match about Ubuntu ... sorry if my question is stupid :( 
I try to google it - but still does not understand

I hold DVD with Ubuntu 16.04 and i have machine with 500GB 
I want to install Ubuntu on as the first operation system ( i need to setup 3 linux destrabution ) on the first 100GB of the disk.

On the installation i have the display of the partition - and where i want to install the Ubuntu - but i don't understand what to fillup here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu just follow the steps provided in the [community's wiki](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), as provided by Mikewhatever in the comments.  Choose the "Something Else" option.  Make sure you make a **Swap** partition.  You only need one Swap partition.  Your other Linux installations can use the same Swap partition.

When you **choose something else** as the install option. Follow the prompts to make the 100Gig partition you have set aside the root "/" partition.  The partition should be formatted as **ext4**.  During the install you can checkmark format as one of the options for that partition.

The installation is quiet seamless.  I can't speak for the other distros, but I'm sure you'll see something similar when running their installation process.

Comment: what is the Swap partition size ?

Comment: At least the size of the amount of ram you have.  I usually go 1.5 the amount of ram.  If I have 10 gigs or ram I'll make the swap size 15 gigs.